# c3p0 getConnection Hangs as Number of Connections are Increased

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, heroku, c3p0

i"m running a web service on Heroku and using New Relic to monitor its performance.  I'm using MySQL with Hibernate on top.  My non default c3p0 settings are the following

```
hibernate.c3p0.maxStatementsPerConnection, 5
hibernate.c3p0.maxPoolSize, 35
hibernate.c3p0.minPoolSize, 5
hibernate.c3p0.initialPoolSize, 10
hibernate.c3p0.acquireIncrement, 10
```

Every single request to my web service hits the database at least a couple of times.  After running a load test of about 200 requests/minute for 10min I see most of time is spent in

```
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection
```

My guess it's waiting for a connection in the connection pool?  The interesting part is as I increased

```
hibernate.c3p0.maxPoolSize, 40
```

the performance was worse off (longer wait time in the same `getConnection` call.  During the test I can see that the max number of `c3p0` connections is indeed open at the MySQL server (max connection set on MySQL's end is `300`, definitely not exhausted).

All of my database functions use the same format

```
public void executeTransaction( Session session, IGenericQuery<T> query, T entity )
{
    Transaction tx = null;

    try
    {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();

        query.execute( session, entity );

        tx.commit();
    }
    catch ( RuntimeException e )
    {
        try
        {
            tx.rollback();
        }
        catch ( RuntimeException e2 )
        {
        }

        throw e;
    }
    finally
    {
        if ( session != null )
        {
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

so I'm certain all sessions are closed, which should translate into connections closing.  Why is the wait time more as I increase the max number of connections?  It seems like  performance  increases from `hibernate.c3p0.maxPoolSize, 25` to `hibernate.c3p0.maxPoolSize, 30`, but drops after `hibernate.c3p0.maxPoolSize, 35`. Are my values far off?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

as a guess, i would try increasing [numHelperThreads](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#numHelperThreads). you have a heavy load; maybe c3p0's administrative Threads are getting backed up. (You should be able to see this if you dump stack traces or use JMX to monitor c3p0. If you have enough helper threads, they should generally be idle(), wait()ing. If they are getting backed up, you'll see them mostly active and runnable, and by JMX you'll see tasks queued.)

an insufficiency of helper threads is consistent with your observed better-then-worse performance with maxPoolSize. initially you get what you want, more Connections at the ready, but then the helper Threads fail to keep up and adding more Connections just makes things worse.

given your settings, helper Threads shouldn't have too much work to do, UNLESS maxStatementsPerConnection is too small. if your app has more than 5 PreparedStatements that are run frequently, then you will end up churning through Statements and tying up helper Threads with Statement close() tasks. you might try making this value larger. it should be approximately (rounding up) the number of distinct PreparedStatements used on an ongoing basis by your application. (You can ignore single or very rarely used PreparedStatements, involved for example in setup or cleanup.) again, monitoring what helper threads are up to would give you information about whether this is the issue. (you'd see backed-up Statement close() tasks.)

so, things to try: increase numHelperThreads, increase [maxStatementsPerConnection](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html#maxStatementsPerConnection) (or set it to zero, to turn off Statement caching entirely.)

good luck!

Comment: thanks for the help.  The number of distinct named HQL queries is about 40.  But for my load test I only use at most 10.  I tried increasing the number of <code>maxStatementsPerConnection</code> to 20, ran the same load scenario, and still there's a lot of the same errors.  I took a look at my database end, and the CPU usage is maxed out.  I have a feeling I'm just hitting the bottleneck of my database (it's an Amazon RDS Medium Instance).

Comment: Essentially I'm using 2-4 servers each with the above settings to access the db in the same manner.  Regardless of how I tweak the servers, 24 max threads/threadpool, 30 max threads/threadpool (2 to even 4 servers running), the db is just running at 100% CPU level.  I don't even get close to the max number of connections allowed on the db, 24*2=48, 35*4=140 < 300.  Using MySQL Admin, I can see almost all the  connections have minimal sleep time before they are used again.  This leads me to believe I'm reaching the limit of the db.

Comment: so, if your db is saturated, that would certainly explain performance problems. but it doesn't obviously explain why you are spending a lot of time in getConnection(), particularly since you seem not to be asking c3p0 to test Connections (which could couple c3p0's performance to that of the dbms). still curious, i think.

Comment: If db is saturated wouldn't all the outstanding threads waiting for a connection to the db spend at lot of time in `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection()` to wait for a connection to be freed?

Comment: it would, if clients are waiting on new Connection acquisition by the pool. but once the pool hits maxPoolSize, there is no new Connection acquisition to wait for (unless some Connections are invalidated, which in your configuration would happen only lazily, as you are not explicitly testing).

Comment: wait. i'm wrong, you're right. indirectly, a saturated db __could__ hurt clients in getConnection() even at maxPoolSize, by virtue of harming the performance of other clients, who therefore check their Connections in more slowly. it's not just new Connection aqcuisition that might be slowed by an overburdened db.

Comment: if connections aren't closed in a quick manner by existing queries (because db is overloaded), all the outstanding db queries will have to wait somewhere correct since max connections is reached?  Do they not wait in `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection()`?

Comment: based on your theory it seems to suggest the great amount of time spent in `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection()` is from threads that have already made the connection and is currently waiting for their queries to be done.  I almost think that `getConnection()` is just for getting a connection.

Comment: no. AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection() is where Threads wait() for a Connection, but they wait() if and only if the pool doesn't already have Connections available. if they are wait()ing, it is for either (1) the pool to acquire new Connections from the dbms; or (2) other clients to return already acquired Connections back to the pool. if getConnection() takes a long time, it's likely that those events are slow. at maxPoolSize, (1) is no longer in play, so it must be (2) that is slow.

Comment: great concise answer.  :)  I guess I'll try out a second layer cache now!